# How do I remove both an undefined union and optionality from an attribute?

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

Here is a reduced code snippet to illustrate the issue:

```js
type A = {
  b?: number | undefined;
}

const a: NonNullable<Required<A>> = {
  b: 0,
};

a.b++;
```

Currently, the `a.b++` operation produces this TSC error:

> TS18048: 'a.b' is possibly 'undefined'.

More descriptive error:

```
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes, diagnostics);
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
project/src/test.ts:9:1 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

9 a.b++;
  ~~~
```

It seems to only happen with the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` option enabled.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCMD8AuKAdgK4C2mEATlAD5REEAmEAZgJYEQMDcKAviigDGAewIBnYFACG+AHKjZRADZKpmJRAA8AJQgBHIqwqdNMAHxmEyNBkz4ADABo+PFFIB0mANReeI8cIa7krCAOYAFB6YAJRcQA)

My assumption was that the combination of `Required` and `NonNullable` should yield a type in which `b` should always be defined, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/mp0M7m).  Are you sure this is a [mre] of what you're seeing?  Either this isn't an actual example of the problem or your compiler is haunted .

Comment: @jcalz it is the example that I used to extract the error messages I posted here. I see from the link posted by T.J. Crowder that it actually works. But I cannot achieve the same result locally. TSC consistently throws that error

Comment: I just created a brand new typescript project to test this and also could not reproduce the same error. I'll look into my tsconfig to see what may be the issue

Comment: The issue is with the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` setting in tsconfig. In [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCMD8AuKAdgK4C2mEATlAD5REEAmEAZgJYEQMDcKAviigDGAewIBnYFACG+AHKjZRADZKpmJRAA8AJQgBHIqwqdNMAHxmEyNBkz4ADABo+PFFIB0mANReeI8cIa7krCAOYAFB6YAJRcQA) you will now be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense; the `undefined` stays because optionality no longer adds it and requiredness no longer removes it; you have to map `NonNullable` over each property, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG8Qow). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki - Nice one on the MRE! :-) Thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) in your code doesn't do what you're expecting: It would remove `null` and `undefined` from `A` itself if it were a union containing them, but it doesn't do anything to `A`'s properties.

But you can create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to do it:

```
type NoNullableProperties<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: NonNullable<T[Key]>;
};
```

Then this works:

```
const a: NoNullableProperties<Required<A>> = {
    b: 0,
};

a.b++;
console.log(a.b);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oCMD8AuKAdgK4C2mEATlAD5REEAmEAZgJYEQMDcKAvjylCQoAOQD2IogBspAQ0xSIABQpjIFYKwgBnADwAVAHwJkaDAG0A0hBBR2UANY2xzKPoC6+cQUkz5igysbd0MefhQUAGMxAm1gKFkvCWk5BWVVdU0dXQAlCABHIlYKTl0YQ2NEVAwsfAAGABo+AVkAOkwAag6eaNixRVapMQBzAAo2zABKLiA)